# Subset All Rows Based on First Value of Column

Tags: r, if-statement, subset

I have a subsetting problem that I am stuck on.  This is a snippet of the data:

```
UniqueID MonthYear FirstObs
ABC123   OCT-18    1
ABC123   NOV-18    0
ABC123   JAN-19    0
ABC123   FEB-19    0
DEF446   MAY-19    1
DEF456   JUN-19    0
DEF456   JUL-19    0
GHI789   OCT-18    1
GHI789   NOV-18    0
```

The dataset is quite large and has a series of rows that look like the above sample.  I want to be able to write a subsetting formula that extracts every row with identical chunks of UniqueIDs together that start with the FirstObs=1 and put them together based on the month from which they originated.  I would have something like the following:

```
Subset1 (all uniqueIDs that originated in October)
UniqueID MonthYear FirstObs
ABC123   OCT-18    1
ABC123   NOV-18    0
ABC123   JAN-19    0
ABC123   FEB-19    0
GHI789   OCT-18    1
GHI789   NOV-18    0


Subset2 (all uniqueIDs that originated in May)
UniqueID MonthYear FirstObs    
DEF446   MAY-19    1
DEF456   JUN-19    0
DEF456   JUL-19    0
```

Ideally, I would have one subset for every chunk that starts with FirstObs=1 from every month.  I know I need to use some series of ifelse and subset functions, but I'm not sure how to go about using them in the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this helps

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>% 
     group_by(UniqueID) %>% 
     filter(first(FirstObs) == 1 & n() > 1)
df3 <- anti_join(df1, df2)
```

it could be also

```
library(stringr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
          group_by(UniqueID) %>% 
          filter(first(FirstObs) == 1, 
                str_remove(first(MonthYear), "-\\d+") == "OCT")
df3 <- anti_join(df1, df2)
```

---

Or `split` into a `list` of data.frames

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(UniqueID) %>%
   mutate(grp = first(FirstObs) == 1 & n() > 1) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   group_split(grp, keep = FALSE)
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  UniqueID MonthYear FirstObs
#  <chr>    <chr>        <int>
#1 DEF446   MAY-19           1
#2 DEF456   JUN-19           0
#3 DEF456   JUL-19           0

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  UniqueID MonthYear FirstObs
#  <chr>    <chr>        <int>
#1 ABC123   OCT-18           1
#2 ABC123   NOV-18           0
#3 ABC123   JAN-19           0
#4 ABC123   FEB-19           0
#5 GHI789   OCT-18           1
#6 GHI789   NOV-18           0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(UniqueID = c("ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", 
"DEF446", "DEF456", "DEF456", "GHI789", "GHI789"), MonthYear = c("OCT-18", 
"NOV-18", "JAN-19", "FEB-19", "MAY-19", "JUN-19", "JUL-19", "OCT-18", 
"NOV-18"), FirstObs = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```